# How is a constructor with infinite arguments made?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I was watching thenewboston "Beginner JavaScript Tutorial - 28 - Arrays" and saw that he created an array by using the method new Array();
My first thought was that Array() is like a constructor that can take a huge if not infinite amount of arguments.
My question is, how does one make such a constructor that can take an infinite amount of arguments?
Do you make thousands of constructors? (That would be a job nobody wants to do.)

Here is an example:

```
var names = new Array('John', 'Mary', 'Thomas', 'Sara');
```

Here i created an array with just 4 arguments but if i am correct, i am able to store thousands of names in this array.
Again, how do you make such a constructor that can take lots of arguments?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Array()` is in fact a constructor that can take a huge amount of arguments. All functions in JavaScript can be called with any number of arguments, regardless of how the functions were declared. The language is distinctly different from a lot of other common languages in that respect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function logArgs() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
logArgs(1, 2, 3); //=> [1, 2, 3]
```

`arguments` is an array-like object containing all the arguments passed to a function.

Of course, the `Array` constructor is most likely implemented natively, but this is how you can make similar functions / constructors of your own.

For more information, see [the MDN doc page on `arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Comment: I understand now. Thank you

Comment: One thing to note is that in ES2015 you can use the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to get an actual Array instance instead of an Array like Object. `function logArgs(...args) { console.log(args); }`

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, passing all parameters in one array is a good practice. And would fix your problem